# HTML5 MP3 player with flash fallback that ACTUALLY works on Blackberry webpages

Tags: flash, html, audio, blackberry, mobile

I have tested loads of HTML5 MP3 players with Flash fallback in the past month, and none seem to work on Blackberry phones (i.e. below OS 7.0, because OS 7 already has some HTML5 support). Do you know of any?

The closest I have gotten so far is for it to play but then the flash never responds when you try to pause or stop it.

P.S. I have trawled S/O posts and tried various suggestions, to no avail on BLACKBERRY phone webpages. I *dislike* duplicates as much as the next guy.

Comment: Does the blackberry support mp3 playback in a web page at all? Are there any sites that do it?

Comment: @Justin808 I am not sure...

Answer (score 2):

Does it *have* to have a **FLASH** fallback? Because [jPlayer](http://www.jplayer.org/) seems to have good java intentions, while running in HTML5. It's open source, too, so I suppose it could have a forked flash version? (just a question, *who uses blackberry anymore anyway?*)

Best of regards,

JXP

Comment: Unfortunately, jPlayer does not work either. It does not have to be a FLASH fallback. Anything that can play audio on a mobile webpage is fine. As for your question, yes I know that blackberries are museum artefacts. But my client needs this to work on blackberry phones, androids and iphones (I already got it working on those two). That is the client's desire and I'm only doing my job. :)

Comment: jPlayer is a jQuery plugin, so you would have to have jQuery installed on the phone as _well_ as jPlayer. Do you have jQuery installed on the phone?

Comment: Yes I'm very familiar with jPlayer. It's a webpage, and yes jQuery is loaded from the Google API via a script tag in the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Yahoo! WebPlayer](http://webplayer.yahoo.com/).  I haven't tried it on blackberry but I've had good luck with it on every other device I've tested.  I believe it used html5 if it can and has a flash fallback if it can't use html5.  Hopefully it works for you.  If not, sorry and good luck!